# After Effects: How do I add a Marker onto a layer?

Tags: after-effects

how do I add a Marker onto a layer in case I have no numpad?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Layer. Then from the top menu:

<kbd>Layer</kbd> => <kbd>Add Marker</kbd>

Or if you want to do it from your keyboard you can modify shortcuts using [this article](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/modify-keyboard-shortcuts.html).

Answer (score 0):

By default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> will add a marker. If you have a region selected then the market will be applied to that region. If nothing is selected, the marker is applied to the comp's timeline at the top.

https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/keyboard-shortcuts-reference.html